# Prove that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\neq \sqrt{x+y}$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers

Tags: proof-writing

I should do it by contradiction. Would finding a counterexample work? For example:

Suppose $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{x+y}$. Then $\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{9}=\sqrt{4+9}$, which means $2+3=\sqrt{13}$ which is a contradiction.

Is this a correct (even though no beautiful) proof?

Comment: $x,y$ are elements of which set?

Comment: @Derpp oh yeah! i forgot ‍♂️ positive real numbers, i will fix it

Comment: You can take any two positive numbers for a counter-example.

Comment: Sure, that works. Why do you doubt it might not?

Comment: @QiZhu Here you go, thank you! if you want post it as an answer i'll give you the best answer

Comment: Just a nitpicking, but you could've also taken an obvious counter-example like $x=y=1$, then $2\ne\sqrt{2}$. (:

Answer (score 3):

If $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=\sqrt{x+y}$,

then $x+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}+y=x+y\Longrightarrow \sqrt x\sqrt y =0$

which is impossible since $x,y$ are positive reals. Contradiction.

Comment: Again, as i said, i did it like this as well, but i just wanted to know if in this other way it would have counted anyway

Comment: I think this should do since there don’t seem to exist any problem in it. In addition, it is just a normal proof by contradiction.

Comment: @pipey, one counter-example indeed is sufficient and I think it is fine, but the contradiction and counter-example don't mean the same thing. In a proof by contradiction, you don't explicitly give an example the statement doesn't hold for.

Comment: @Invisible so the contradiction i gave in the proof above it's not a "proper contradiction"?

Comment: @pipey: To disprove a statement, a single counter example is sufficient. To prove a statement, you need to prove it for all cases. If you state, 'All swans are white' you need to produce only one black swan to disprove that statement. If you want to prove that statement 'All swans are white', you need to produce all swans in the universe and demonstrate that they are white.

Answer (score 1):

Assume it is true. Square both sides. You'll get $x+y+2\sqrt{xy}= x+y$.

$\implies \sqrt{xy} = 0$
$\implies xy=0$

$ \implies x=y=0$

or $ x=0, y \neq 0$

or $ y=0, x \neq 0$

So this statement isn't true for all $x,y$, but only the above 3 cases.

Comment: I know the proof, i did it like you did it as well, but i just wanted to know if what i wrote would have been considered a proof anyway

Comment: yes, you need only one counter example to disprove a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a single example counts as a complete, correct proof depends on the tacit quantifier behind the assertion "$\sqrt x+\sqrt y\not=\sqrt{x+y}$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers." If the careful formulation is

$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+: \sqrt x+\sqrt y\not=\sqrt{x+y}$$

then yes, a single example suffices. But if the careful formulation is

$$\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+: \sqrt x+\sqrt y\not=\sqrt{x+y}$$

then a single example is not enough (and a proof along the lines of the other answers here is required).

To move the negation around, the first formulation says that the equation $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=\sqrt{x+y}$ (with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+$) is not an identity, whereas the second formulation says the equation has no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill?

Let $x,y \ge 0$, real.

Then set $a:=√x;$ $b:=√y;$

We have

LHS: $a+b;$

RHS: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{(a+b)^2-2ab}\le $

$\sqrt{(a+b)^2}=a+b.$

Equality: $\iff$ $ab=0,$ i.e. $a=0$ or $b=0.$

Used: $f(x)=√x$  is an increasing function.